# Unable to get data between two years

Tags: sql, oracle, between

I am not getting data between two years, below is between condition

```
to_char(Wfc.APPLYDTM,'MM/DD/YYYY') between '12/11/2019' and '01/10/2020'
```

but I am getting data between '12/11/2019' and '12/31/2019' & '01/11/2020' and '01/01/2020' for these dates but not between two different years.

Please help

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: Your question implies that you want to compare `DATE` values, however you compare **strings** values.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `TO_DATE` instead of `TO_CHAR`, and then compare against valid Oracle date literals:

```
SELECT *
FROM Wfc
WHERE TO_DATE(APPLYDTM, 'MM/DD/YYYY') BETWEEN date '2019-12-11' AND date '2019-01-10';
```

Note that if `APPLYDTM` already be a date, then you don't need to call `TO_DATE` on it.  It doesn't make sense to convert your data to character, if you intend to work with it as a date.

Comment: So you did it wrong, or your data doesn't fit. Please, edit the original question, post the WFC table description as well as several rows of sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your data to `Date` to be able to compare correctly.

The main idea is you should compare `date` value instead of `string` value.

```
to_date(Wfc.APPLYDTM,'MM/dd/yyyy') between to_date('12/11/2019','MM/dd/yyyy') and to_date('01/10/2020','MM/dd/yyyy')
```

Read [here](https://it.toolbox.com/question/oracle-sql-convert-format-of-a-date-to-dd-mm-yyyy-092514) to more details.

Comment: Although CONVERT function exists in Oracle, it is used for converting strings from one character set to another. Therefore, your suggestion won't work, as far as Oracle is concerned (and yes, the OP tagged the question with the "Oracle" tag).

Comment: My bad, the OP tag `sql` so it makes me confuse. Thanks sir @Littlefoot

Comment: No problem; happens to me as well, sometimes.

Comment: How about using `to_date('12/11/2019','MM/dd/yyyy')` to convert date in `oracle` sir?

Comment: Yes, that would convert a string to a date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Abhijit jadhav

Answer (score 0):

Do not convert date/time values to strings!  Use the built in functionality.

Your logic is most simply expressed as:

```
Wfc.APPLYDTMbetween >= DATE '2019-12-11' AND
Wfc.APPLYDTMbetween < DATE '2020-01-11'
```

Note that the date constants are provided using the `DATE` keyword.  This supposed ISO 8601 standard date formats (happily!).

Also note the use of `>=` and `<` rather than `BETWEEN`.  The `date` data type in Oracle can include a time component -- even if you don't see it when you query the table.  This ensures that all date/times are included in the range.

As an added benefit, this can use an index on `(APPLYDTMbetween)`.  Using a function usually precludes using an index, unless you have defined a function-based index.